# Redemption versions and functions backwards compatible

Tags: backwards-compatibility, outlook-redemption

My software is currently using a version of Redemption from 2015, some customers are running into freezing issues on the current version of Outlook, so I'm interested in upgrading to the latest version of Redemption. Will the latest version of Redemption be backwards compatible with the functions we are already using from the 2015 version of Redemption?

Comment: I'd recommend checking logs to find out what could cause the delay. There can be multiple reasons, not only Redemption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all versions of Redemption are backward compatible (binary and source code) – you can just swap the dll.